# static const int in CUDA for a templated code

Tags: c++, c++11, static, cuda

I have the following code snippet:

```
class Mesh{
  public:
    static const int DIM = 3;
    // several more static constants here
}

template <class M>
Coords{
  public:
    int c[M::DIM];
    // some more members using static constants of M here
}
```

And I would instantiate some coords with:

```
Coords<Mesh> coords;
```

Now this basically works good for me.

According to the documentation, CUDA 6.5 does not support `static` members at all (Programming Guide, E.2.6.1. Data Members, no link available). CUDA 7.0 adds support for `static const` members (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#const-variables).

As long as I use CUDA 6.5, **how could I replace** the `static const int`? `#define` is probably not a good option, because templatization would no longer work as intended.

Comment: which compiler errors did you get when trying the `static const` member? please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @m.s.: that is kind of irrelevant here because static class members are a well documented non-supported language feature in CUDA through to CUDA 7.0

Comment: @talonmies I just [read that](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#data-members), however I could not reproduce a compiler error when trying the above code.

Comment: @m.s.: so you wrote a kernel which takes a class containing a static member as an argument and compiled it, and it works?

Comment: @talonmies yes, I wrote an non-sense kernel, but it compiled: http://pastebin.com/120dpRSN

Comment: @m.s.: I don't have the ability to compile anything right now, but if it builds that is a very interesting development. CUDA 7, I presume?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82310/discussion-between-m-s-and-talonmies).

Comment: I'm pretty sure [`const` - qualified variables](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#const-variables) are an exception:  "Let `V` denote a namespace scope variable or a **class static member variable that has const qualified type** and does not have execution space annotations (e.g., `__device__`, `__constant__`, `__shared__`). `V` is considered to be a host code variable.   The value of `V` may be directly used in device code, if `V` has builtin floating point or integral type, and it has been initialized with a constant expression before the point of use."

Comment: Based on my previous comment, I don't see anything wrong with OP's posted code or the example provided by @m.s. which compiles cleanly for me also.  Therefore I believe that the question is not well-posed, and the request by m.s. for an MCVE is valid.  I see no basis for OP's claim "BUT I run into enormous problems when I try to compile this for CUDA..."  As such I have downvoted the question as a signal to future readers that it may contain misleading information.

Comment: Didn't know that `static const int` is allowed in CUDA 7.0. I think it's very unfortunate to have a paragraph saying "Static data members are not supported." with no reference that there ARE exceptions. I tried to clarify the question and reduced it to "how can I replace static const int", without stating too much about what's supported and what's not.

Comment: Removed my downvote.  The question is now phrased appropriately, IMO.  Actually, when I attempt to compile the code provided by m.s., it compiles cleanly for me under CUDA 6.5 as well.  I suspect that the support for `static const <builtin-type>` class members was added prior to CUDA 7.0, but apparently the documentation didn't get updated until CUDA 7.0.  Alas, the world is not a perfect place, and when the documentation update in section E.2.8 was made, section E.2.6.1 did not get changed to reflect that.  I have filed a documentation RFE with NVIDIA to suggest an  update to E.2.6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with enums?

```
class Mesh{
  public:
    enum { DIM = 3 };
    // several more constants declared as enums here
}

template <class M>
Coords{
  public:
    int c[M::DIM];
    // some more members using enums of M here
}
```